# Проверка на пустой массив

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Возникла непонятная ситуация: 
c сервера (Laravel) приходит массив с ошибками, если их нет - то пустой массив `[]`.
Все попытки проверить на пустой массив не увенчались успехом...
Пример если есть ошибка:

```
{"email":["These credentials do not match our records."]}
```

Не знаю почему, но `Object.keys(errors).length` не работает.
Пример использования:

```
computed: {
    error() {
        return !!Object.keys(this.errors).length;
    }
},
mounted() {
     console.log(this.errors);
     console.log(this.error)
},
```

В консоли:

```
{"email":["These credentials do not match our records."]}

true
```

и

```
[]
true
```

Comment: я, наверное, что-то не так понимаю. 1)добавьте пж вопрос к своему сообщению. 2) Все попытки проверить на пустой массив не увенчались успехом© - например?

Comment: например if (this.errors.length == 0)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20html%20%3D(a%2C%20...b)%3D%3E%7Bdocument.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend'%2CString.raw(a%2C%20...b)%2B'%3Cbr%3E%5Cn')%7D%0Alet%20o%20%3D%20%7Berrors%3A%20%5B%5D%2Ccheck()%20%7B%0A%20%20let%20isArray%20%3D%20'%5Bobject%20Array%5D'%20%3D%3D%3D%20Object.prototype.toString.call(this.errors)%0A%20%20html%60isArray%3A%20%24%7BisArray%7D%60%0A%20%20let%20isZero%20%3D%20null%0A%20%20if%20(isArray)%20isZero%20%3D%200%20%3D%3D%3D%20this.errors.length%0A%20%20html%60isZero%3A%20%24%7BisZero%7D%60%0A%7D%7D%0Awindow.onload%20%3D%20o.check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно получить ключи массива через `Object.keys(errors)` и проверить их длину.

```js
const errors = {"email":["These credentials do not match our records."]}

if (Object.keys(errors).length)
  console.log('Ошибка найдена')
  
const errors2 = {}

if (Object.keys(errors2).length)
  console.log('Во втором ошибка найдена')
```

Могу дать свою функцию для формирования строки сообщения из ошибок, вдруг пригодится:

```
function showServerError ({ data }) {
  const { errors } = data
  let message = ''

  if (errors) {
    for (let field in errors) {
      if (errors.hasOwnProperty(field)) {
        for (let error of errors[field]) {
          // можете добавить префикс field(имя поля с ошибкой) если надо
          message += `${error}\n`
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    message = data.message
  }

  // можете вывести через alert, например
  alert(message)
}
```

Comment: Object.keys(errors).length не работает как хотелось бы... В моём случает всегда возвращает true... Обновил шапку

Comment: Как пустой массив может возвращать true?! Сами выполните `!!Object.keys([]).length`, будет false.  `[]` не строка случайно?

Comment: Как здесь залить скриншот из браузера? Я это прекрасно понимаю, но результат говорит сам за себя

Comment: Оказывается да, сервер отдаёт строку